# Can't traverse through a C linked list

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

Task is to create a linked list consisting of objects. User inputs data for each individual `Node` in the `main` and then the object is being passed to `push`, which creates the list.

The problem comes in the `printList` function, where the condition for a `break` is never met.
For some reason the line `head = head->next` doesn't do anything, as the address of `next` with every iteration remains the same.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int a;
    char asd[30];
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

void push(Node**head, struct Node* object);
void printList(Node *head);

int main() {

    struct Node {
        int oA;
        char oAsd[30];
        struct Node *next;
    };

    struct Node *object = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    int c = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("This int will be stored in Node %d.\n", ++c);
        scanf("%d", &object->oA);
        getchar();
        if (!object->oA) {
            break;
        }
        printf("This string will be stored in Node %d.\n", c);
        gets_s(object->oAsd, 30);
        if (!(strcmp(object->oAsd, "\0"))) {
            break;
        }
        push(&head, object);
    }
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}

void push(Node ** head,  struct Node* object)
{
    Node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp = object;
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}


void printList(Node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        puts("No list exists.");
        exit(9);
    }

        while (1) {
            printf("-------------------------------\n");
            printf("|Int: <%d> |||| String: <%s>.|\n", head->a, head->asd);
            printf("-------------------------------\n");
            if (head->next) {
                printf("\n\n%p\n\n", head->next);

                head = head->next;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
}`
```

Comment: Why are you redefining `struct Node` inside `main`?

Comment: `push(&head, object);` is a type error. Doesn't your compiler complain about this?

Comment: `tmp = malloc(...); tmp = ...` is a memory leak.

Comment: @melpomene I'm learning how to pass objects to functions, assign objects oneanother and create lists consisting of multiple fields.

Comment: That answers literally none of my questions.

Comment: @melpomene 'function' - incompatible types - from 'Node *' to 'Node *'  is what I get in VS, but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You have two different struct types in your program. For some reason you've given them both the name `Node`, but they're still different types.

Comment: @melpomene What makes their types different? They consist of the same fields, only naming is different.

Comment: Why should they be the same? There are clearly two separate `struct { ... }` definitions in the code, each of which creates a new type.

Comment: `tmp = object;` ==> `*tmp = *object`

Comment: Don't "repeat" `struct Node` inside `main`

Comment: @4386427 Worked like a charm, why are the * required there? Neither tmp or object are double pointers.

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned, you've defined two different `Node` structs. Whether you think they're the same outside of simple naming is not relevant. The compiler doesn't just assume you mean the same thing. Why do you have a redefined `Node`?

Comment: @OlegPlachkov Without the * you are assigning the **value** of a pointer to another pointer. That's not what you want! You want to assign the **value of the struct** pointed to by `object` to be assigned to the struct pointed to by `tmp`. Hence the *

Comment: @lurker I thought in order to assign 2 structures one another they had to be of the same type. Plus the name I gave the object in main initially wasn't accepted by the compiler when I passed it to functions so I had to use what worked.

Comment: You've defined two structures, with different scopes, using the same name. Your `push` function accepts a pointer to `Node`, but you call it with the address of a *different* `Node`. Why don't you just use the same type definition for the `Node` used inside `main`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major problems in your code:

- You define `struct Node` both outside `main` and inside `main`
- Here `tmp = object;` you copy the value of a pointer to another pointer but you really want to copy the value of a struct to another struct, i.e. `*tmp = *object;`.

Besides that - don't put `head` as a global variable.

So the code should be more like:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int a;
    char asd[30];
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

void push(Node**head, struct Node* object);
void printList(Node *head);

int main() {
    Node *head = NULL;

    struct Node *object = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    int c = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("This int will be stored in Node %d.\n", ++c);
        scanf("%d", &object->a);
        getchar();
        if (!object->a) {
            break;
        }
        printf("This string will be stored in Node %d.\n", c);
        gets_s(object->asd, 30);
        if (!(strcmp(object->asd, "\0"))) {
            break;
        }
        push(&head, object);
    }
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}

void push(Node ** head,  struct Node* object)
{
    Node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    *tmp = *object;                    // Copy the struct
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}


void printList(Node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        puts("No list exists.");
        exit(9);
    }

        while (1) {
            printf("-------------------------------\n");
            printf("|Int: <%d> |||| String: <%s>.|\n", head->a, head->asd);
            printf("-------------------------------\n");
            if (head->next) {
                printf("\n\n%p\n\n", head->next);

                head = head->next;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
}
```